# Deploy EAR on different Wildfly undertow server

Tags: deployment, jboss, ear, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have two different  inside wildfly undertow subsystem in order to use two interface on different ip and send different ssl certificate for different domain

```
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>

        <server name="default-server">

            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>

            <https-listener name="https-listener" socket-binding="https" security-realm="https_realm1"/>

            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">

                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>

                 <access-log pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access"/>

            </host>

        </server>

           <server name="default-server_secondary">

            <http-listener name="default_secondary" socket-binding="http_secondary"/>

            <https-listener name="https-listener_secondary" socket-binding="https_secondary" security-realm="realm2"/>

            <host name="server.mydomain.com" alias="server.mydomain.com">

                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>

                 <access-log pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access_secondary"/>

                 <filter-ref name="server-header1"/>

            </host>

        </server>
```

By using this configuration and others on interface and socket binding I correctly set my environment.

But the problem is deploy the EAR file in default-server_secondary inside host server.mydomain.com.

How to?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

Make and edit jboss-web.xml in WAR module

default-server_secondary 
    server.mydomain.com